# IOS SDK + Youtube API + NoLinkedYouTubeAccount

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I have add youtube APi in my application and I have successfully authorized my account and get access token from google via auth 2.0.

but now i want to add comment on video and i am getting error as below:
1. invalide token
2. NoLinkedYouTubeAccount
etc.

i thought, i am not able to correctly use and understand Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
statement of google and i am confusing how to pass my token with my call.

My code is as below:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
        [theRequest addValue: @"application/atom+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [theRequest addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",@"my token" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        [theRequest addValue: @"2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version"];
        [theRequest addValue: @"key=mykey" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-GData-Key"];

        [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Can you help me to solve this issue and suggest me to call correct way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to access with an Service account rather than an actual YouTube account.
You can check out [Objective C samples](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/YouTubeSample) from YouTube and use YouTube [Objective-C client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/).